# How to load resource files or package: URIs in Dart?

Tags: dart

There is a way to get the path of the currently executing script and then find the resource files relative to this location, but there is no guarantee that the directory structure is the same when the application is published.

Does Dart provide a generic way to load resources (files, data, ...) in a way that works also with `pub run` or `pub global run`?

Asked another way, how do I dynamically load the contents of a `package:` URI, in a Dart app, at runtime?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update**
The [resource](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/resource) package was published.

**Update**
This is being reworked. The `Resource` class will be moved to a package.

**Original**

There is a new `Resource` class in Dart (tested with `Dart VM version: 1.12.0-edge.d4d89d6f12b44514336f1af748e466607bcd1453 (Fri Aug  7 19:38:14 2015)`)

**resource_example/lib/resource/sample.txt**

```
Sample text file.
```

**resource_example/bin/main.dart**

```
main() async {
  var resource = const Resource('package:resource_example/resource/sample.txt');
  print(await resource.readAsString());
  // or for binary resources
  // print(await resource.readAsBytes());
}
```

Executing

```
dart bin/main.dart
```

prints

```
Sample text file.
```

Executing

```
pub global activate -spath . 
pub global run resource_example:main
```

also prints

```
Sample text file.
```

It's also possible to pass the content of a variable as a resource. This might for example be convenient in unit tests to pass mock resources.

```
const sampleText = "Sample const text";

main() async {
  var uriEncoded = sampleText.replaceAll(' ', '%20');
  var resource = new Resource('data:application/dart;charset=utf-8,$uriEncoded');
  print(await resource.readAsString());
}
```

Arbitrary file or http uris are supported as well but this might not work when using `pub run` or `pub global run` when using relative paths.

```
main() async {
  var uri = new Uri.file('lib/resource/sample.txt');
  var resource = new Resource(uri.toString());
  print(await resource.readAsString());
}
```

For more details see
- http://blog.sethladd.com/2015/08/dynamically-load-package-contents-with.html
- https://codereview.chromium.org/1276263002/

Comment: Does it work when you globally activate a package from pub.dartlang.org ?

Comment: Interesting question. I haven't published one yet where I could try it with.

Comment: Just tried it. Doesn't work yet: `Could not resolve a package location for base at file:///Users/sethladd/.pub-cache/global_packages/resourcetest/bin/resourcetest.dart.snapshot`